# Retrofit calls inside for loop , java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have a nested retrofit server requst calls inside a for loop and i got an error

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2359304
How i can fix this.Is there any other way to loop Retrofit server calls..

```
List<ID> idList = new Arraylist<>();
int idCompleted = 0;
```

idList.size() is greater than 30000;

Here My Function :

```
 public void getNewList(){
        for(int i=0;i<idList.size();i++) {
            int iValue = i;
            Call<String> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getMyApi().getList(idList.get(i).getId(), "A");
            call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    String responseA = response.body().toString();

                    Call<String> call1 = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getMyApi().getList(idList.get(iValue).getId(), "B");
                    call1.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                            String responseB = response.body().toString();
                            

                            addToFile(responseA,responseB);

                            idCompleted ++;
                            if (idCompleted == idList.size()) {
                                
                                    Log.i("Finished : ", "Yes")
                            }else {
                               getNewList();
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                           idCompleted ++;
                            if (idCompleted == idList.size()) {
                                
                                    Log.i("Finished : ", "Yes")
                            }else {
                               getNewList();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    idCompleted ++;
                            if (idCompleted == idList.size()) {
                                
                                    Log.i("Finished : ", "Yes")
                            }else {
                               getNewList();
                            }

                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is going to be shown on a RecyclerView, you should call the network requests in the RecyclerView Adapter so it will only do a few at once.

If not, you should modify your loop so it can only call a few at once instead of calling all at the same time as it does at the moment.

No device has enough RAM for 30000 network requests at the same time. Just do 2-3 at the same time.